# Regex to strip domain from URL for all scenarios?

Tags: regex

I know there are similar questions to this in the past, but none of the solutions actually work for all scenarios.

So far I have built this regex:

```
(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z\-]+\.[a-z-A-Z\.]+)
```

And it works for all these examples (it extracts google.com):

```
https://www.google.com/something/something
https://google.com/something/something
https://www.google.com/
https://google.com/
https://www.google.com
https://google.com
www.google.com
google.com
http://www.google.com/something/something
http://google.com/something/something
http://www.google.com/
http://google.com/
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.com.hk
http://google.com.hk
```

However it doesn't work for this example (it extracts mail.google.com):

```
http://mail.google.com
```

I can't simply change the regex to `(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z]+\.)?([a-zA-Z\-]+\.[a-z-A-Z\.]+)` as that will cause `http://google.com.hk` to be matched as `com.hk`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to extract? `google.com`?

Comment: Correct, google.com

Comment: (http:\/\/|https:\/\/) can be simplified to (http(s)?:\/\/)

Comment: In your definition of regex, you have marked www. as optional match and if you similarly doesn't want mail. to also be an optional match you will have to give it too there or else like you said in input text http://google.com.hk you will end up matching com.hk only

Comment: Is is not very clear as to what you exactly want. Can you post some more input sample data and what you expect it to match?

Comment: I want a regex which can strip the domain from a URL, but for all URL scenarios. So if you look at my examples, you can see I can successfully strip out "google.com", except for when there is a non-www subdomain. Let me know if I need to further clarify.

Comment: You will either need to incorporate the [Public Suffix List](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List) into your regular expression or you will need to do post-processing afterwards. There also are `.co.uk` and various other "double-dot" domain suffixes involved with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the approach I outlined in my comment above, you will need to capture all suffices and then work your way towards the front of the domain name:

```
^(?:(?:https?://)?(?:(?:\w+\.)*?(\w+\.(com\.hk|co\.uk|com|net|org|hk)\b))).*
```

Note that the list at the end needs to be sorted by descending length!

You will need to expand the list at the end, and you can make the regexp a bit faster by eliminating the backtracking, but it works with the above test cases:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if( m!^(?:(?:https?://)?(?:(?:\w+\.)*?(\w+\.(com\.hk|co\.uk|com|net|org|hk)\b))).*! ) {
        print "$1\n";
    } else {
        die "Failed '$_'";
    }
}

__DATA__
https://www.google.com/something/something
https://google.com/something/something
https://www.google.com/
https://google.com/
https://www.google.com
https://google.com
www.google.com
google.com
http://www.google.com/something/something
http://google.com/something/something
http://www.google.com/
http://google.com/
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.com.hk
http://google.com.hk
http://google.hk
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/qJ4vV7/15)

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't work for google.com.hk. It returns google.com. You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/qJ4vV7/12

Comment: Thank you! The suffix list needed to be sorted by descending length, edited

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks

Comment: I've noticed an issue with this. If "hk" is added to the list, it breaks "com.hk".

Comment: Ah - no, you're right, the middle `\w+` needs to be made less greedy. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You're awesome.