# Extract ISP From hostname C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am using ipstack to get information about the user's IP. It gives me the hostname, but I would like to use the hostname to get the ISP. The hostname I am getting is:

> d9687b05.cm-24.dynamic.ziggo.nl

Where I would like to extract the `ziggo.nl` <-- thats the ISP.

Of course it wont allways be ziggo, and it wont allways be `.nl`, so how would I go about getting that part of the hostname on different ones?

Comment: you always want last two part?

Comment: What about https://aaisp.net.uk/ ? You will need to consider the https://publicsuffix.org/ to solve that problem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641486/regex-to-strip-domain-from-url-for-all-scenarios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to strip domain from URL for all scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641486/regex-to-strip-domain-from-url-for-all-scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to capture the last two words,

```
.*\.(\w+\.\w+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ReE6je/1)

**Explanation:**

- `.*\.` --> Matches zero or more any character followed by a literal dot
- `(\w+\.\w+)` --> Matches one or more word char followed by literal dot followed by one or more word char

Here is a sample C# code,

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pattern = ".*\\.(\\w+\\.\\w+)";
        var match = Regex.Match("d9687b05.cm-24.dynamic.ziggo.nl", pattern);
        Console.WriteLine("DomainName: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

This gives following output,

```
DomainName: ziggo.nl
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Regex I would do something like this:

```
string isp = "";
string[] split = hostname.Split('.');
int len = split.Length;
if(len >= 2)
   isp = $"{split[len-2]}.{split[len-1]}";
```

Or this:

```
    string isp = "";
    string hostname = "d9687b05.cm-24.dynamic.ziggo.nl";
    int a = hostname.LastIndexOf(".");
    if(a>0)a=hostname.LastIndexOf(".", a-1);
    if(a!=-1) isp = hostname.Substring(a+1);
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9H5MLn)

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex and extra explanations it can be done in readable and comprehensible way ;)

```
var names = hostname.split(".");
var notRequired = Math.Max(0, names.Count() - 2);

var isp = string.Join(".", names.skip(notRequired));
```